# pyQT4 statusbar setpalette (python3)

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt, background-image, statusbar, qmainwindow

A little question about the statusbar() of QMainWindow in pyQT4

Is it possible to set a palette for a statusbar() ? So far I have one working very well but I'd like to put a image in its background just like I did with my widgets.

So here's what I have try :

```
  #StatusBar
            self.statusbar = self.statusBar()
            self.tboard.msg2Statusbar[str].connect(self.statusbar.showMessage)
            #Set background Color
            BackgroundPalette = QtGui.QPalette()
            BackgroundPalette.setBrush(QPalette.Background,QBrush(QPixmap("MenuBare.png")))
            self.setAutoFillBackground(True)
            self.statusbar.setPalette(BackgroundPalette)
```

Which is doing nothing.

So, is it even possible ? If not I'll just bin this statusbare and do the exact same thing with a widget...

Thanks !
Blob.

Comment: Just wild guess, did you mean something like `self.statusbar.setPalette(BackgroudTemplate)`?

Comment: As such :   BackgroundPalette = QtGui.QPalette()
        BackgroundPalette.setBrush(QPalette.Background,QBrush(QPixmap("MenuBare.png")))
        self.setAutoFillBackground(True)
        self.statusbar.setPalette(BackgroundPalette)

(not displaying anything)